# Using a WebClient to save an image with the appropriate extension

Tags: c#, .net, image, webclient

I'm required to retrieve and save an image from a website to my local folder.  The image type varies between .png, .jpg and .gif

I've tried using

```
string url = @"http://redsox.tcs.auckland.ac.nz/CSS/CSService.svc/";
string saveLoc = @"/project1/home_image";
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile(url, saveLoc);
}
```

but this saves the file 'home_image' in the folder without the extension.  My question is how do you determine the extension? Is there a simple way to do this? Can one use the Content-Type of the HTTP request? If so, how do you do this?

Comment: You need to give the file name with the path `@"/project1/home_image/Someimage.png"`

Comment: I don't know the extension though, that's what I need to find out so that I can save it with the correct one.

Comment: You need to get mime type from response's headers, map it to extension and use it. Unfortunately `WebClient` is too high level method to give you access to headers.

Comment: You need to use `HttpWebRequest` in that case. But my question is if you know the image that you need to download you might as well know the extension! Does your service method stream an image?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use a `WebClient`, then you have to extract the header information from `WebClient.ResponseHeaders`. You'll have to store it as a byte array first, and then save the file after getting your file information.

```
string url = @"http://redsox.tcs.auckland.ac.nz/CSS/CSService.svc/";
string saveLoc = @"/project1/home_image";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] fileBytes = wc.DownloadData(url);

    string fileType = wc.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType];

    if (fileType != null)
    {
        switch (fileType)
        {
            case "image/jpeg":
                saveloc += ".jpg";
                break;
            case "image/gif":
                saveloc += ".gif";
                break;
            case "image/png":
                saveloc += ".png";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(saveloc, fileBytes);
    }
}
```

I like my extensions to be 3 letters long if they can.... personal preference. If it doesn't bother you, you can replace the entire `switch` statement with:

```
saveloc += "." + fileType.Substring(fileType.IndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Makes the code a little neater.

Comment: for ppm files the mime type is image/x-portable-pixmap, so the 2nd option will produce a ".x-portable-pixmap" file, which probably won't be associated with your image program.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Your URL");
 request.Method = "GET";
 var response = request.GetResponse();
 var contenttype = response.Headers["Content-Type"]; //Get the content type and extract the extension.
 var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Then save the  stream